# Xamarin Persistent color chooser

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, get, set

I make a button and Color picker to xamarin.forms app, but I want to make it when I choose one color (ex. red) and close app, when i reopen it to see this red color automatic picked. I try to use this code but Preferences not working with Color:

```
public Color ColorPicker
{
    get => Preferences.Get(nameof(ColorPicker), color.Red);
    set
    {
        Preferences.Set(nameof(ColorPicker), value);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ColorPicker));
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: In Xamarin.Forms, the Application subclass has a static Properties dictionary which can be used to store data. Such as `Application.Current.Properties ["myColor"] = color;` Check the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#properties-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Color.FromHex(string value)` method needs a `string` type parameter. Try to convert the **value** to string type in the custom class.

Check the code:

Custom Converter class

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var color = Color.FromHex(value as string);
        return color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Page.xaml

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:StringToColorConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>


<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding Color_string, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Thank you it working perfect now, just i need to add `get => Preferences.Get(nameof(Color_string), Color.Red.ToHex());`

Comment: Another problem now is I can not set new color 
`set
            {
                Preferences.Set(nameof(Color_string), value as string);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color_string));
            }`

i change background color with button but set event not rise up...

Comment: It seems that there is no command to assign a value to the property in the 'set' method. Only the `Preferences.Set` exists which is to save a value in preferences. Try to add the `the_property = value;` code.

Answer (score 1):

You can store Xamarin.Forms.Color as a string like this:

```
public string ColorPicker
{
    get => Preferences.Get(nameof(ColorPicker), Color.Red.ToString());
    set
    {
        Preferences.Set(nameof(ColorPicker), value);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ColorPicker));
    }
}
```

Then you can bind it for instance to Label like this:

```
<Label TextColor="{Binding ColorPicker}" />
```

Make sure you set BindingContext in your view. You can read more about Binding [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings)

Answer (score 0):

I is not possible to make it like this. Because i need to use converter after to make string=>color. I am trying this:

```
    public class StringToColor : IValueConverter
{
    ColorTypeConverter converter = new ColorTypeConverter();
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //return value.ToString(); //not working
        //return (Color)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(value.ToString())); //not working
        return Color.FromHex(value.ToString()); //not working too
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and add this convetor to xaml

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:StringToColor x:Key="str" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>


    <Label Text="TEST" FontSize="Title" TextColor="{Binding ColorPicker,
    Converter={StaticResource str}}"/>
```

but nothing happend...

Comment: The `Color.FromHex(string value)` method needs a `string` type parameter. Try to convert the **value** to string type in the custom class.